# Cant use eslint rule created by typescript-eslint

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

[image][image]I have create an rule, using typescript-eslint.
Here is package

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.14.6",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.54.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.54.1",
    "eslint": "^8.35.0",
    "prettier": "^2.8.4",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@typescript-eslint/utils": "^5.54.1"
  }
```

Here is his `tsconfig`

```
    {
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2016",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "sourceRoot": "",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "strict": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["./*.ts"]
}
```

I build a rule by `tsc`, and install it in another project.
Here is .eslintrc.js
But unfortunately cant load the rule.
Why?

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es6: true,
    commonjs: true,
    "amd": true,
    "node": true
  },
  extends: "eslint:recommended",
  overrides: [],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 7,
    sourceType: "module",
  },
  plugins: ["translation"],
  rules: {
    "translation/check-length": [2, { min: 3 }],
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `package.json` file probably has the option `"type":"module"` specified. ESLint docs specify that you have to use `.eslintrc.cjs` when running ESLint in JavaScript packages that specify `"type":"module"` in their package.json.

Just change the filename from `.eslintrc.js` to `.eslintrc.cjs`. That should solve the issue